# Node elements are not printing in Single Linked List Program

Tags: c, struct, turbo-c++

I have created here a C Program in TurboC++. This simple program goal is to just create a linked list, insert every element at the end of the list and then print the value of the nodes.(Edited The program is somewhat changed to make it easier for me to understand but still the problem of nodes not being priniting exists)
The problem is, some of the node elements are not printing

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node ND;
void main()
{
  ND *start,*current,*temp;
  start=NULL;
  do
  {
    temp=(ND*)malloc(sizeof(ND));
    printf("\n Enter Node Value");
    scanf(" %d",&temp->data);
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
      start=current=temp;
    }
    else
    {
      current->link=temp;
      current=temp;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDo You Want TO Continue?(Y/N)");
  }while(toupper(getchar())!='N');
  current=start;
  printf("\nThe Elements OF Linked List ARE:");
  while(current!=NULL)
  {
    printf(" %d",current->data);
    current=current->link;
  }
}
```

Comment: Even the [multi-decade-old Turbo C++ console IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-to-use-turbo-c) has an integrated debugger. You should use it to track down where the problems are. Unrelated, you're missing `ctype.h` and `stdlib.h` from your include list, both of which should be included for `toupper` and `malloc` support respectively.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To put it in simple words, this is not a 'debug my code for free' service.

Comment: I have written the shortest code above and i have stated my problem that the node elements of the list are not printing...

Answer (score 2):

You printing list from wrong element. You should start from head.
like:

```
temp1 = head;
while(temp1!=NULL)
{
  printf(" %d",temp1->data);
  temp1=temp1->link;
}
```

By the way your head element will be always NULL.
Here is correct way to add elements to list:

```
if (head == NULL)
{
    head = temp;
}
else
{
    temp1 = head;
    while (temp1->link != NULL)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->link;
    }
    temp1->link = temp;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %d",temp->data)` isn't right either, and invokes undefined behavior. Prolly wanna mention that.

Comment: Yeah i have corrected that but still it's not printing and i've also added stdlib.h and ctype.h

Comment: I have updated the program and this time i have used even a simpler method but the problem is that the elements are not printing i just enter the elements one by one and after that when i press N to stop adding more elements than instead of printing the elements entered the program just quits in turboc++.I think there is a runtime error in the above program...

Answer (score 0):

The program is now working correctly i have made some changes to make this program easier to understand.Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node ND;
void main()
{
  ND *head,*tail,*temp1;
  int n;
  char ch;
  printf("\nEnter Data?(y/n)\n");
  scanf(" %c",&ch);
  fflush(stdin);
  if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
  {
    tail=(ND*)malloc(sizeof(ND));
    printf("\n Enter Node Value");
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    tail->data=n;
    tail->link=NULL;
    head=tail;
    printf("\nDo You Want TO Continue?(Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);
    fflush(stdin);
  }
  while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
  {
    printf("\n Enter Node Value");
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    tail->link=(ND*)malloc(sizeof(ND));
    tail->link->data=n;
    tail->link->link=NULL;
    tail=tail->link;
    printf("\nEnter More Data?(y/n)\n");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);
    fflush(stdin);
  }
  printf("\nElements Of Linked List Are:");
  temp1=head;
  while(temp1!=NULL)
  {
    printf(" %d",temp1->data);
    temp1=temp1->link;
  }
  printf("\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  getch();
}
```